# C# Six Labors ImageSharp runtime error System.Memory 4.0.1.0 Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, imagesharp, system.memory

In a project loaded in Visual Studio 2019 where image manipulation is needed, the [Six Labors ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) library is used. But when trying to load an image, the runtime error pops up:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In the project where ImageSharp is used, a System.Memory reference is installed and the properties say it's `4.0.1.0`. But when compiled and checking the details of the DLL it says `4.6.28619.1`

I've tried to delete the reference and reinstall with NuGet but got the same version difference. The NuGet package also doesn't show the version `4.0.1.0` listed under the 'Previous versions' section.

Tried to reinstall difference available versions of `System.Memory` but that didn't work. Also searched the issues on the GitHub repo, but this was not mentioned.

Is ImageSharp linked to `4.0.1.0` and no matter what version you install, it will show `4.0.1.0`?

How can I solve this so the runtime error doesn't show and I can use ImageSharp?

**Update**:
Installing the nightly build 'solved' the problem. This one uses System.Memory >= 4.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest [1.0.0-rc0001](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp/1.0.0-rc0001) release.

When working on NET Framework there were sometimes binding redirect problems caused by net standard funkiness. We now reference a much higher version.